# How to make app minimize with back button?

Tags: android

I need to minimize app after user info input with `backButton`.
What do I do wrong?

This is the `backButton` code:

```
 backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {

     if (sendThread != null) {
       //sendThread.cancel();
     }

     if (receiveThread != null) {
       //receiveThread.cancel();
     }

     //acceptThread = new AcceptConnection();
     //acceptThread.start();
     textsListAdapter.clear();
     viewFlipper.showPrevious();
     deviceArrayAdapter.clear();
   }
 });
```

Comment: `What i do wrong?` - you try to "minimize"  the app on back bitton press.

Comment: yes that's exactly what i need, i need to minimize the app after user input info not the open menu

Comment: First, there's no such thing on Android like "minimize the app". You can go in background but that's not guaranteed your app stay there. If you need things like you describe then it smells like bad app design usually. Back button is for going back. Do not override standard system behavior as this simply sucks like hell from user perspective.

Comment: so it' s not possible?

Comment: What you need that for?

Comment: Client asked to do this in his project

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Comment: tried this to, but still get open the menu not minimize the app

Comment: moveTaskToBack(true); try this.

Comment: still the same, app didn't minimize

Comment: This will minimize only current activity. IF you do have other activity then it may not closs all activity/

Comment: i'm stack now, what i need to change, for minimize the app after user input info not to open menu

Comment: Replace your code in onbackpressed with moveTaskToBack(true);  then check if it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution it will exit from the app

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
 System.exit(0);
```

Comment: still the same, opens the menu not minimize